# Middleware redirecting creates an errors. PWA app, NextJS 14, App router

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-auth

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
const session = await getToken({ req: request, secret: process.env.SECRET });
const pathName = request.nextUrl.pathname; // Get pathname of the current request
// Check if a session exists and if the request path is '/login'
if (session && pathName === "/login") {
// If yes, clone the URL and change its pathname to the home page
const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
url.pathname = "/";
return NextResponse.redirect(url);
// Check if user not logged in, and on the main page
  }
if (!session && pathName !== "/login") {
// If yes, clone the URL and change its pathname to the login page
const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
url.pathname = "/login";
return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }
// Continue processing the request if the conditions are not met
return NextResponse.next();
}
```

when i do if `(!session && pathName !== "/login")` than i have an errors:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at webpack.js?v=1710935355737:1:1)

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main-app.js?v=1710935355737:1:1)

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at app-pages-internals.js:1:1)

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at page.js:1:1)

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at layout.js:1:1)

Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

If i write if `(!session && pathName === "/")` Everything works as it should, but I have a dynamic id and I can't do the same check for all of the pages

I tried googling, I couldn't find anything. I expect that when the user clicked on the "Logout" button on any page in the application, it redirected to the "Login" page, it even redirects and shows the login button

```
"use client";

import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

function Login() {
  return (
    <main>
      <button onClick={() => signIn("azure-ad", { callbackUrl: "/" })}>
        Login with Microsoft
      </button>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

but I get the errors described above, and button don't work